# How should I add css classes to Flask wtform "labels"

Tags: flask-wtforms

I am experimenting with Flask and flask-user.  The Registration template calls `render_field()`  on a few items, one is email.  for example, in my editied copy of `registration.html` there is:

```
            {% if user_manager.USER_ENABLE_EMAIL %}
                {{ render_field(form.email, tabindex=220) }}
            {% endif %}
```

This yields:

```
<div class="form-group  ">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required="" tabindex="220" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

How can I add classes to the `label` tag only?

I've looked at the `wtforms` code but if there is an answer in there it's not jumping out at me.  I see what appears to be the `kwargs` passed to `render_field` being added to the `input` tag but I am not seeing anything touching the label.

Answer (score 0):

I found this.  I was looking for `render_field` in `*.py` files. I now see that it is defined in the `_macros.html` file in the `flask_user/templates` dir.